# Using Python from a XML file ,I want to get only the tags that have a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

```xml
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
            <results preview='0'>
            <meta>
                    <fieldOrder>
            <field>count</field>
               </fieldOrder>
            </meta>
        <result offset='0'>
            <field k='count'>
                <value><text>6</text></value>
            </field>
        </result>
    </results>
```

From this XML , I want to get only the tags that have values. i.e From this xml I want only the 'text' tag, 'fields' tag.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm pretty sure you could have googled this and I'm certain if you search on this site, you'll find someone has already answered your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Load xml, traverse it (eg recursively), return tags with non-empty text.

Here as generator:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def getNonemptyTagsGenerator(xml):
    for elem in xml:
        yield from getNonemptyTagsGenerator(elem)
    if len(xml) == 0:
        if xml.text and xml.text.strip():
            yield xml

xml = ET.parse(file_path).getroot()
print([elem for elem in getNonemptyTagsGenerator(xml)])
```

Result:

```
[<Element 'field' at 0x7fb2c967fea8>, <Element 'text' at 0x7fb2c9679048>]
```

You said wanted "tags", so those are the `Element` objects.

Comment: I get ERROR : "  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' " when i use this on other xml files.

Comment: Fixed. Now there's no `text` var and we first check the existence of `xml.text`, then we check whether it still exists when we strip whitespace from its ends.